# Using ./update.sh instead of update.sh to execute it

Tags: shell

Suppose I have a command update.sh.
Since . refers to the current directory (on Linux/UNIX systems), I think that ./update.sh and update.sh should be the same.
But it turns out that until I use

```
    chmod +x update.sh
```

./update.sh doesn't work.
Why is it so?
Why do we sometimes run a command like this - ./update.sh instead of update.sh?

Comment: To execute, use either `./update.sh` or `sh update.sh`. The first assumes the 1st line of the file has `#!/bin/sh` or something indicating the binary that executes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update.sh` will search the PATH for a file with that name. If `.` is not in your path it won't execute that file. `./update.sh` indicates that you want to execute exactly this file.

I guess that without the `.` you are executing a different update.sh. If you want to make sure the `update.sh` in the current directory is executed by /bin/sh independent of the permissions on the file or the `#!` line in the file run it as

```
 /bin/sh ./update.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

`chmod +x <script>` sets the *executable* bit on your file, telling the shell it's OKAY to treat that file as an executable.  This is how the system differentiates between normal files and executable files in unix.

For shell scripts, you can also run them directly by passing them into a shell first like

```
sh ./update.sh
```

This way you don't need to use `chmod +x` first.

Additionally, the shell will only look for scripts in the directories specified by your `PATH` environment.

If `PATH` does not contain `.`, meaning "the current directory", then the shell will not run any scripts in the current directory unless you give it the full path, which in your case is `./update.sh`.  Note that the *executable* part from above still applies here.